# Customize Content Query Web using Internal Names not guides

Tags: content-query-web-part

I am trying to configure the Content Query Web Part to show my custom fields defined in the underlying content type.

The following code snippet is placed in a custom template in the ItemStyle.xsl to display the names of my fields.  However they are coming back as a GUIDs instead of the expected internal name.

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
  P:<xsl:value-of select="name()" /><br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

result

```
P:ListId
P:WebId
P:ID
P:_x007B_fa564e0f_x002D_0c70_x002D_4ab9_x002D_b863_x002D_0177e6ddd247_x007D_
P:_x007B_94f89715_x002D_e097_x002D_4e8b_x002D_ba79_x002D_ea02aa8b7adb_x007D_
P:_x007B_1d22ea11_x002D_1e32_x002D_424e_x002D_89ab_x002D_9fedbadb6ce1_x007D_
P:_x007B_28cf69c5_x002D_fa48_x002D_462a_x002D_b5cd_x002D_27b6f9d2bd5f_x007D_
P:_x007B_1df5e554_x002D_ec7e_x002D_46a6_x002D_901d_x002D_d85a3881cb18_x007D_
P:_x007B_d31655d1_x002D_1d5b_x002D_4511_x002D_95a1_x002D_7a09e9b75bf2_x007D_
P:_x007B_8c06beca_x002D_0777_x002D_48f7_x002D_91c7_x002D_6da68bc07b69_x007D_
P:_x007B_30bb605f_x002D_5bae_x002D_48fe_x002D_b4e3_x002D_1f81d9772af9_x007D_
P:_x007B_ba3c27ee_x002D_4791_x002D_4867_x002D_8821_x002D_ff99000bac98_x007D_
P:_x007B_c5c4b81c_x002D_f1d9_x002D_4b43_x002D_a6a2_x002D_090df32ebb68_x007D_
P:_x007B_8fca95c0_x002D_9b7d_x002D_456f_x002D_8dae_x002D_b41ee2728b85_x007D_
P:_x007B_39360f11_x002D_34cf_x002D_4356_x002D_9945_x002D_25c44e68dade_x007D_
P:_x007B_543bc2cf_x002D_1f30_x002D_488e_x002D_8f25_x002D_6fe3b689d9ac_x007D_
P:_x007B_43bdd51b_x002D_3c5b_x002D_4e78_x002D_90a8_x002D_fb2087f71e70_x007D_
P:_x007B_9da97a8a_x002D_1da5_x002D_4a77_x002D_98d3_x002D_4bc10456e700_x007D_
P:_x007B_b3d973fd_x002D_80e8_x002D_4362_x002D_954c_x002D_0fb8907a92ea_x007D_
P:_x007B_76d190e3_x002D_8f4d_x002D_4b63_x002D_9854_x002D_87203a3df38c_x007D_
P:_x007B_acf271e1_x002D_b940_x002D_4015_x002D_8f68_x002D_f170694606cb_x007D_
P:_x007B_578bd580_x002D_d31f_x002D_4ff4_x002D_af0b_x002D_2e96e5733cda_x007D_
P:_x007B_b9e6f3ae_x002D_5632_x002D_4b13_x002D_b636_x002D_9d1a2bd67120_x007D_
P:PubDate
P:FileExtension
P:FileSize
P:DocumentIconImageUrl
P:OnClickForWebRendering
P:Description
P:Title
P:LinkUrl
P:Style
P:GroupStyle
P:__begincolumn
P:__begingroup
```

Why are my fields coming back as GUIDs and not internal names?  Ultimately I want to simply select my fields using internal names so I can format an html table.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@My_x0020_Field"/>
```

Thanks for your help.